# Error on run: Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Targets/0/Values} does not match type {Array}]

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

This CF is being created in **YAML** not JSON.

I am building Systems Manager Maintenance Windows, Targets and Tasks through Cloudformation.

When creating the stack, the Resources: MaintenanceWindow: section complete successfully. It's the next section (below) that is failing. Not sure about the last section as we never get there.

Here is the location for the full template: https://pastebin.com/DNEkLPGS

I have tried using validators and everything (YAML and the CloudFormation Validators) and everything comes back as good.

Here is the section giving errors:

```
Parameters:
  MaintenanceTargetName:
    Description: Maintenace Target Name (No Spaces)
    Type: String
  MaintenanceTargetDescription:
    Description: Sample - UAT Servers
    Type: String
    MaxLength: '128'
  MaintenanceTargetTarget:
    Description: Tag Key should equal 'AgentUpdate'
    Type: String
    Default: tag:AgentUpdate
  MaintenaneTargetKeyValue:
    Description: True or False
    Type: String
    Default: True
    AllowedValues:
      - True
      - False

Resources:
  MaintenanceWindowTarget:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTarget'
    Properties:
      WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      ResourceType: INSTANCE
      Targets:
        - Key: !Ref MaintenanceTargetTarget
          Values: !Ref MaintenaneTargetKeyValue
      Name: !Ref MaintenanceTargetName
      Description: !Ref MaintenanceTargetDescription
```

Running the template gives the following error:

MaintenanceWindowTarget |  **CREATE_FAILED** | Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Targets/0/Values} does not match type {Array}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the issue, it was a formatting problem:

```
Resources:
  MaintenanceWindowTarget:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTarget'
    Properties:
      WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      ResourceType: INSTANCE
      Targets:
        - Key: !Ref MaintenanceTargetTarget
          Values: !Ref MaintenaneTargetKeyValue
      Name: !Ref MaintenanceTargetName
      Description: !Ref MaintenanceTargetDescription
```

The issue lied in the Targets section:

```
      Targets:
        - Key: !Ref MaintenanceTargetTarget
          Values: !Ref MaintenaneTargetKeyValue
```

The above was incorrect. Below is the correction:

```
      Targets:
        - Key: !Ref MaintenanceTargetTarget
          Values: 
          - !Ref MaintenaneTargetKeyValue
```

Hope this helps others!!

Comment: This did solve my issue for `AWS::SSM::Parameter` `Tags` property. It should be defined as in my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394634/4842112

Answer (score 6):

For Resource `AWS::SSM::Parameter` Property `Tags` should be defined as following.

```
Tags:
    Technical:AppID: !Ref ApplicationId
    Technical:AppName: !Ref ApplicationName
    Technical:Owner: !Ref Owner
    Technical:Env: !Ref Environment
    ProjId: !Ref ProjectId
```